# SAS Proc Compare - dates in different formats

Tags: sas, compare

I'm exporting a SAS dataset to excel, then importing it back to SAS, and for the purpose of validation, doing a proc compare to ensure all values are the same. Unfortunately, the dates, which are in DATETIME20. in the original SAS datasets, are in MMDDYY10. when I bring the dates values back from excel into SAS. I could live with that, but the value comparison results shows that no values match, listing 04/04/06 in base, and 04APR2006 in compare.

Is there a way to make the proc compare ignore formats, or a way to specifically check if any variable are MMDDYY10. then assign that variable DATETIME20.?

I'm not experienced in SAS, but this is what I'd like to do - ie. the commented out bits:

```
proc compare b = myBase c = myComp listvar warning;
* ignore date formats;
run;
```

or

```
proc import datafile = myExcelFile 
        out = myBase
        dbms = xls replace;
    guessingrows = 32767; 
    getnames = yes;
            * if anyVariable MMDDYY10. then thatVariable DATETIME20.;
    sheet = "mySheet";
run;
```

The validation must be done in SAS - no manipulation of excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS stores DATETIME values in seconds and DATE values in days. 
If you really were storing only the dates in those DATETIME variables then to compare you will need to convert your DATETIME values to DATE values.

```
data for_compare ;
  set myComp ;
  datevar = datepart(datevar);
  format datevar mmddyy10.;
run; 

proc compare b = myBase c = for_compare listvar warning;
run;
```

If you really were actually storing DATETIME values then why even bother to compare as they will not match since Excel has lost the time part.

Comment: Actually it's possible Excel hasn't lost the time part - you can sometimes get them as fractional days, where `dhms(datevar,0,0,0)` will restore them.

Comment: I am not sure if I find that fact comforting or scary.

Comment: Eh, I think it's just one of those "converting from Excel is not ideal" things. :)

Comment: The original datetime values have time 00:00:00, so I really just need to compare the date value, as you have focused on.

Answer (score 1):

`DATETIME20.` vs `MMDDYY10.` is not just a difference in formats - that wouldn't be a problem.

It is a difference in the underlying value, because a datetime is the number of seconds since 1/1/1960 00:00:00 while a date is the number of days since 1/1/1960.  Very different nubmers (by a factor of 86400).

You'll need to control this on import, likely, or else convert after-the-fact.  You can try `DBSASTYPE` to tell Excel to import it as datetime:

```
proc import datafile = myExcelFile 
        out = myBase
        dbms = excel replace;
    getnames = yes;
    sheet = "mySheet";
    dbdsopts="dbsastype=(yourdatevar='datetime')";
run;
```

I think you have to use `DBMS=EXCEL`not XLS to use `dbdsopts`, but not 100% sure. You also may be able to use the option `USEDATE=NO`, though i'm not sure if that will convert the date from 1/1/1900 to 1/1/1960 properly (see ["Processing Date and Time Values in Microsoft Excel"](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63184/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003077073.htm#a003159578)).

If you want to convert after the fact, either use `DATEPART` to convert the datetime to date, or use `newdtvar = DHMS(datevar,0,0,0)` to convert the date to datetime.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use dbms = excel. This might be due to excel being 32 bit, and SAS is 64 bit. As you suspect, the dssastype then does not work. I appreciate the tips, though, and am following through for now.